# Combine environment xml configuration files

Tags: xml, powershell

I want to create generalized environments configuration configs and would like to implement it in the following way. Here is file structure:

```
core
  | publish.xml
project
  | repository
      | environment
          | publish.xml
      | publish.xml
```

There is hierarchical files/folders structure where in each folder might exist or not `publish.xml` file. I want to read folder from the root down to `environment` folder and read that xml file in each folder. Each next level will either override existing configuration or add new one.

Here is the configuration file example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ExcludeDatabaseAuditSpecifications>True</ExcludeDatabaseAuditSpecifications>
    <AllowIncompatiblePlatform>True</AllowIncompatiblePlatform>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

and one more xml from lower level:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <IncludeCompositeObjects>True</IncludeCompositeObjects>
    <AllowIncompatiblePlatform>False</AllowIncompatiblePlatform>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <SqlCmdVariable Include="users">
      <Value>users</Value>
    </SqlCmdVariable>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

as the output I wish to get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <IncludeCompositeObjects>True</IncludeCompositeObjects>
    <AllowIncompatiblePlatform>False</AllowIncompatiblePlatform>
    <ExcludeDatabaseAuditSpecifications>True</ExcludeDatabaseAuditSpecifications>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <SqlCmdVariable Include="users">
      <Value>users</Value>
    </SqlCmdVariable>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Here is the code I wrote already. It can add to the end of the document, but not to the PropertyGroup or ItemGroup

```
if ($null -eq $SecondXml) {
    return $FirstXml;
}

if ($null -eq $FirstXml) {
    return $SecondXml;
}

$finalXml = $FirstXml;
foreach($el in $SecondXml.Project.PropertyGroup) {
    $name = $($el| Get-Member -MemberType property | Select-Object Name).Name;
    if (!($null -eq $finalXml.Project.PropertyGroup.$name)) {
        $finalXml.Project.PropertyGroup.$name = $el.$name;
    } else {
        $xmlElt = $finalXml.CreateElement($name);
        $xmlText = $finalXml.CreateTextNode($el.$name);
        $xmlElt.AppendChild($xmlText);
        $finalXml.LastChild.AppendChild($xmlElt);
        $finalXml.LastChild.AppendChild($xmlElt);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can definitely do this "by hand", as you're currently doing, but you might wanna look into using XSLT for this instead